# If checkbox is checked and user clicks on the button do this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox with a button, i want when user check the check box and click on the button show an alert and when checkbox is unchecked and user clicks on the button do something else.

I did something but i need help to accomplish it.
Any help greatly appreciated

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#remember').click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            alert("This is checked and you cliked");
        } else {
            alert("This is unchecked and you cliked");
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3fd7cpqg/)

Comment: try replacing (this.checked) with ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are showing alerts in Checkbox's onclick. You would need to add the code in button's onClick.

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fd7cpqg/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#buttonId').click(function() {
        if ($('#remember').is(':checked')) {
            alert("This is checked and you cliked");
        } else {
            alert("This is unchecked and you cliked");
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jquery [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) selector for  this:-

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    if ($('#remember').is(':checked')) {
        alert("This is checked and you cliked");
    } else {
        alert("This is unchecked and you cliked");
    }
});
```

You can set id or class to button

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#btnEnter').click(function() {
    if ($('#remember').is(':checked')) {
        alert("This is checked and you cliked");
    } else {
        alert("This is unchecked and you cliked");
    }
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3fd7cpqg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

use **[Prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**;

```
 $('[type=button]').click(function () {
    if ($("#remember").prop("checked")) {
        alert("This is checked and you cliked");
    } else {
        alert("This is unchecked and you cliked");
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3fd7cpqg/10/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
     $('#buttonId').click(function() {
        if ($('#remember').prop('checked')) {
          alert("This is checked and you cliked");
        } else {
         alert("This is unchecked and you cliked");
        }
    });
});
```